# What is the correct way to create mock object in unit test

Tags: magento2, testing, unit-tests, phpunit, magento2.2

Now days I am focusing on TDD development, and I am following the `Magento` test class for reference. So firstly I look into `Contact` module (as it is the small module) and I found that in `DataTest.php` from `Magento\Contact\Test\Unit\Helper\DataTest.php` it gets the mock object from `construct` argument. like in `setUp` you can find it like,

```
  protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->objectManagerHelper = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);
        $className = \Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class;
        $arguments = $this->objectManagerHelper->getConstructArguments($className);
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
         */
        $context = $arguments['context'];
        $this->scopeConfigMock = $context->getScopeConfig();
        $this->customerSessionMock = $arguments['customerSession'];
        $this->customerViewHelperMock = $arguments['customerViewHelper'];
        $this->helper = $this->objectManagerHelper->getObject($className, $arguments);
    }
```

from here `customersession` `Magento` get the mock object from construct argument.

```
        `$this->customerSessionMock = $arguments['customerSession'];`
```

But in some of test class `magento` create the mock object by using `createMock` method. Like,

```
$this->customerSessionMock = $this->createMock(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::class);
```

So which way I should follow to create `mock` object ? and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit test object manager helper has been introduced to make it easier to create tests for legacy classes with lots of dependencies, automatically mocking all the dependencies. Avoid using it for new code, instantiate the class under test directly and mock interfaces instead of concrete classes wherever possible.

`createMock` has been introduced in PHPUnit 6, and Magento 2.2 finally upgraded to that version. It also automatically mocks (actually: stubs) return values of methods if not specified otherwise, so that the unit test object manager helper is not necessary anymore.

If you write code for Magento 2.1 and must support PHPUnit 4, the preferred way to create mocks is:

```
$this->getMockBuilder()->getMock(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::class);
```

The old `$this->getMock()` does not exist anymore in PHPUnit 6

### Example

Today, the `Magento\Contact\Test\Unit\Helper\DataTest` set up that you showed would look like this:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    /*
     * First, create all mocks where we will define expectations later in the tests
     */
    $this->scopeConfigMock = $this->createMock(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class);
    $this->customerSessionMock = $this->createMock(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::class);
    $this->customerViewHelperMock = $this->createMock(\Magento\Customer\Helper\View::class);

    /*
     * Then prepare the context object which contains one of the mocks
     */
    $context = $this->createMock(\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context::class);
    $context->method('getScopeConfig')->willReturn($this->scopeConfigMock);

    /*
     * Finally instantiate the class under test and pass all the dependencies explicitly
     */
    $this->helper = new \Magento\Contact\Helper\Data(
        $context,
        $session,
        $customerViewHelper
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. But I have doubt on contact helper. In this class magento get the object from  `getConstructArguments` . so both are same ?

Comment: @KeyurShah the unit test helper automatically created mocks for the dependencies and the test accesses them via `getConstructArguments` to be able to modify expectations. I can update the question with a more detailed explanation, but you should know that this is not the preferred way for new code

Comment: Okay, got it :) , thanks a ton, feel free to edit the question If you have more explanation. Just few days ago I started TDD development. @Fabian

Comment: @KeyurShah updated, let me know if you have more questions